# Using the Samsung Galaxy Tab Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

First time Android developer here, and I'm having trouble getting a desired emulator to work in the "Java - ADT". All of the tutorials and posts I've found so far have been little to no use!

After downloading the ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, I extracted the zip to a specified location: "C:\Users\Hunter\Documents\Android Development".

Now I'm trying to use this [Samsung GALAXY Tab Emulator](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator) (which downloads as a zip file) inside the ADT. The instructions on the download page are vague and outdated; they make use of the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" which no longer exists!

Now, on to the questions:

> > Where should I extract the Samsung GALAXY Tab Emulator zip file to so that the ADT can find and make use of it?
> >
> > After extraction, how do I install the Samsung Tab emulator in the ADT?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I did it for my situation ( which is on Mac OS X, but I assume the steps would be similar on Windows, just different directories ):

1. Downloaded zip file, as normal
2. Once it is unzipped, I took the `<User Home>/Downloads/addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8/skins/GALAXY Tab` folder and copied it.
3. I found where my android sdk stuff is ( in my case, `<User Home>/android-sdks` ).  The key is the `<User Home>/android-sdks/platforms`.  In that folder, there is a folder per Android version.
4. I pasted the above "GALAXY Tab" folder to each Android version I cared about, specifically to the `<Android Version>/skins/` folders.

I actually renamed "GALAXY Tab" to "GALAXY_Tab", so that in my case I ended up with this:

```
pwd;ls -lrtd */skins/GALAXY*
<User Home>/android-sdks/platforms
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-22/skins/GALAXY_Tab
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-21/skins/GALAXY_Tab
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-20/skins/GALAXY_Tab
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-19/skins/GALAXY_Tab
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-18/skins/GALAXY_Tab
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 work  staff  646 Jul 22 18:19 android-17/skins/GALAXY_Tab
```

Note that there is a good chance your "android" stuff will be in a different place, and may not even be named "android-sdks".  In your case, it is probably under `C:\Users\Hunter\Documents\Android Development\platforms`, or somewhere close to that folder.

Now, as for actually using it in the AVD manager:

1. Bring up AVD manager
2. Go to "Device Definitions" tab
3. Because "Create Device" almost never works for me, I normally just find a device that closely resembles the device I want.  In this case, the '7.0" WSVGA (Tablet)' generic device definition was the closest, so I clicked that device, then clicked "Clone".  I changed the name to "Galaxy Tab", but kept pretty much everything else the same.  Once I was done filling out this form, I clicked "Clone Device".
4. Once the device was cloned, I clicked my new "Galaxy Tab" device, then clicked "Create AVD"
5. In the AVD form, I changed Target to "API Level 19", CPU to "armeabi-v7a", chose my new "GALAXY_Tab" skin for Skin, updated the SD Card to 18 MB ( as per the link you provided ), and updated any other values I felt like changing ( I change as few of these values from the defaults as possible ).

Hopefully this answers your question.  I have used this basic principle for installing a few skins, and then using them in virtual devices.

**7/24/2015 edit:**

I found out today that my Galaxy Tab emulator is not considered a tablet by my application.  I use Cordova, so my application runs inside WebView ( or Chrome for Android ), so I depend on the userAgent.  In my case, userAgent has "Mobile" in it, so my code, whether right or wrong, considers the device to be a phone, not a tablet.  A real device does not have this problem ( userAgent does not have "Mobile" in it ).  Minor point, and does not invalidate my advice, but did want to warn people.  I suspect it has something to do with the Android version I am testing against, Android 4.4.4, but that is a side issue to my overall project, and so will not be troubleshooting it.